# Skip Auth Routes with K8s + Ingress-Nginx +oauth2-proxy

Tags: nginx, oauth-2.0, oauth2-proxy

I am using [oauth2-proxy](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/manifests/tree/main/helm/oauth2-proxy) with k8s+ingress-nginx. The way nginx redirects to oauth is always through the annotation
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://$host/oauth2/auth in the ingresses defined by every service.

With this annotation the URL /oauth2/auth always reaches the oAuth POD

> [2023/04/20 11:53:41] ***.***.com GET - "/oauth2/auth" HTTP/1.1
> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64

If I set /oauth2/auth in skip_auth_routes any ingresses that have the above annotation will skip authentication. This is correct, but s there a way to pass the Ingress URL to oAuth so that I can set it in skip_auth_routes?

Comment: Your question does not really make sense, but I'm facing a similar issue. How do I setup skippable routes with K8 and OAuth2 proxy?

Comment: You can skip routes configuring the property skip_auth_routes in your configfile https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/overview/#config-file

Comment: That doesn't work if you have an ingress setup with auth-url/auth-sign-in.

Comment: Correct, but If it were possible to pass the current URL at nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: https://$host/oauth2/auth as parameters and were able to read parameters this option could be done. The only problem is that the skip_auth_routes option does not work with parameters